# Jekyll - How to change pygments syntax highlighting Font family?

Tags: css, fonts, jekyll, font-family, pygments

In the syntax.css , I've added this:

```
.highlight {
font-family: "Sudo";
}
```

but nothing change:
[image]

How to change the font-family?

Comment: Use your developer tools to check that the style is not being overridden, then ensure that the font is available on the page (installed locally or included with Google Fonts or similar). It's pretty hard to debug a problem like this without a site URL or repo so might be worth including that in future.

Comment: thank you, the problem is I used wrong keyword for it, in keyll syntax for the pygments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked, I use:

> Pre,code{
>   font-family: sudo;
>   }